# $Span(A)=S$; show that no proper subset of $A$ generates $S$ iff $A$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $Span(A)=S$.
>   Then, show that no proper subset of $A$ generates $S$ iff $A$ is linearly independent.

*My approach:*
$\bbox[7px,border:1px solid green]{\text{$(\Rightarrow)$only-if part:}}$
**Given:** $Sp(A)=S$
No proper subset of $A$ generates $S$.
**To Show:** $A$ is linearly independent.
If possible, assume A is linearly dependent.
$Sp(A)=S$
$\Rightarrow A$ generates $S$ but, $A$ is linearly dependent
$\Rightarrow$ there exists a proper linearly independent subset $B$ of $A$, generating $A$ $_{...(1)}$
Since, $B$ generates $A$ and $A$ generates $S$, we have that $B$ generates $S$ $_{...(2)}$
, which is a contradiction.
Therefore, $A$ is linearly independent.
$\bbox[7px,border:1px solid green]{\text{$(\Leftarrow)$if part:}}$
**Given:** $Sp(A)=S$
$A$ is linearly independent.
**To Show:** No proper subset of $A$ generates $S$.
Suppose, there exists a proper subset $B$ of $A$, generating $S$. Also, $Sp(A)=S$.
So, every element in $S$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $A$ as well as vectors in $B$. But, $B$ is also a subset of $A$. $_{...(3)}$

---

**Doubts $(1),(2)$:** If my approach is correct, I know intuitively that these conclusions are correct. But, I would like to know if there are theorems supporting this.
**Doubt $(3)$:** I am not sure how to proceed from there (I started with a proof by contradiction).

---

[**EDIT**: I made corrections in the statement before $(3)$, as pointed out(?)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your writing, though you have the correct idea in your mind. For example, the statement $S$ can written as a linear combination of ... makes no sense.

Here is the correct way to write the proof: suppose no proper subset of $A$ generates $S$. If $A$ is not linearly indpendent then there exists an equation of the form $\sum c_ix_i=0$ with $x_i \in A$ for all $i$ and not all of the coefficients are $0$. If $c_{i_0} \neq 0$ we can rewrite the equation in the form $x_{i_0}=\sum_{i\neq i_0}b_ix_i$. Now let $A'=span(A\setminus {x_{i_0}})$. Then $A'$ is a proper subset of $A$ which generates $S$.

Conversely, suppose $A$ is linearly independent and let $A'$ 
be a proper subset of $A$. Then there is  a vector $x \in A\setminus A'$. This vector cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $A'$ because $A$ is linearly independent. Hence $A'$ does  not span $S$.

Comment: What do you mean by $span(A/x_{i_{o}})$? Assuming $x_i$ _s_ are elements of $A$, is $A'=span(A/c_{i_{o}})$ what you meant? Also, how do we get that $A'$ generates $S$ from that statement, I am sorry but I am unable to understand.

Comment: @ZaIra span of a set is the set of all linear combinations of elements of that set. Every element of $S$ is a linear combination of elements of $A$. If one of these elements is $x_{i_0}$ then use the fact that $x_{i_0}$ is itself a linear combination of other elements of $A$ to conclude that $A\setminus x_{i_0}$ spans $S$.

Comment: oh i realize you used $\setminus$ and not $/$. Thank-you!